# Two different login systems won't run separately on the same domain

Tags: php

I have a user system and database at mysite.com and another user system and database at mysite.com/2.

The problem I discovered is that when a user is logged in at site.com then they load mysite.com/2 and it show another user account.

I don't know what cause this problem, I think its something related to sessions. I think that the solution is to logout the user of mysite.com when they try to go to mysite.com/2.

I tried to use `session_destroy()` but no luck with it.

Comment: I didn't got a thing here

Comment: If you use the same session for both mysite.com and mysite.com/2 and you check the same session variable on both sites, and check that variable in different account databases, then that will be indeed what happens.

Comment: Well, you probably used same session names for both sites... Just change them.

Comment: Please use `example.com` for example URIs. `mysite.com` is a real site, and I doubt you are United Online Web Services, Inc.

Comment: @HanletEscaño how o change sessions names for both sites

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is data leaking between applications through a shared session, then the solution is to use different sessions for each site. Use the [`session_name()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) to give each application it's own session name.

```
<?php
    session_name("MYAPP");
    session_start();
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    session_name("MYOTHERAPP");
    session_start();
?>
```

---

Alternatively, don't host multiple applications on the same VHost.

Comment: this should be at the top of my script at index.php ?

Comment: If you're using sessions already, then you'll already be using `session_start`. It should be wherever (and, for that matter, everywhere)) you are using `session_start`.

Comment: no i am not using session_start anywhere

Comment: @user3080937: you probably are without being aware of it, possibly in a library you're using. Sessions won't work without it.

Comment: @halfer i have searched all my file for session_start and no file contain it

Comment: @user3080937: I don't know how you've got it to work, in that case, but this is the first thing you need to fix. Have a look at the manual page at php.net/session_start.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of, both the two sites are under one domain, it will create SessionCookie to store authentication details.

Both the 2 sites creates same **SessionCookie** name. thats the problem...

use

```
session_name();
```

to create different names for session...

//session name for mysite.com

```
session_name("MYSit1");
```

//session name for mysite.com/2

```
session_name("MYSit2");
```

Comment: this should be at the top of my script at index.php ?

Comment: set it before you setting the session.

Comment: thanks for quick response here is my index.php http://pastebin.com/WFaWPggm . where to add your code to it?

Comment: where is the session_start(); is that in global.php

Comment: no session_start(); in index.php neither in golbal.php

Comment: then where you sets the session in your project..

Comment: i have searched for session_start(); in every file on my script but nothing present

Comment: do u have a problem to work on as freelancer with fees?

Comment: i mean i will pay you to check and fix this problem in my site if ok add me on skype: pamela.stroman1